# How do I find a patent from its number?

Tags: search, patent-search, number

How can I find the patent with patent number **P53958US00**?

Comment: Doesn’t look like a number from any patent system I’m familiar with. Do you have any other information?

Comment: How did you find this number?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I found an site online about a Canadian startup claiming some sort of nanotextile and referencing that number as an application. http://awnnanotech.com/

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Could it be a provisional identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that number leads to anything, but the company  that is mentioned in the article that attributed  that number to them does have a published US patent application. It is Methods And Apparatuses For Harvesting Water From Air  2020/0298174. https://patents.google.com/patent/US20200298174A1/en

Comment: Good idea to search on the company name. Might also want to link to their website.

Comment: The number of OP looks like an internal reference of the IP firm handling the case, which cannot lead to anything as you said.